# Firebase Stream using authStateChanges, wont return my custom model?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I believe i have misunderstood the ? operator, and I'm not sure how to return a valid custom model. My reasoning to think this, is my "Customuser?" function, cant return null, which i dont understand? I would think it could catch a null reference.

My current attempt, looks like this:

```
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

//create user obj based on firebase user
Customuser? _customuser(User user) {
  return user != null ? Customuser(uid: user.uid) : null;
}

//auth change user stream
Stream<Customuser?> get streamedUser {
  return _auth.authStateChanges().map(_customuser);
}
```

The custom model simply looks like this:

```
class Customuser {
  final String? uid;

  Customuser({this.uid});
}
```

I'm not sure how to handle the ? operator on my custom model, so that it works with my stream.

The error message is attached.

[image: Error message]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your error message, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add `?` to your User param and try again

```html
Customuser? _customuser(User? user) {
  return user != null ? Customuser(uid: user.uid) : null;
}
```

Comment: Why is the solution always something stupid, am i right xD hihi.
Thank you so much, for reaching out :)